# json-encoded string got cut off when sent by POST over cURL (SSL enabled)

Tags: php, json, ssl, curl

I have PHP code that uses CURL for sending 3 different arrays from one server to another over POST request. One of those arrays may contain variable number of records, and others - always one record. Prior to sending each array is json-encoded. 3 different POST-parameters then used, 1 for each array. SSL is enabled.

So everything works just fine while the 'variable-size' array is NOT bigger then 50 records (app 15 kB).
But as soon as I try to send say 51 or more records - json decoding error ('Syntax error') occurs on the receiving server when decoding that array.

Can someone please give me any idea/suggestion on what can get wrong when transmitted data is grown bigger and how can this be avoided/fixed?

Note: both servers have identical config: Win7, Apache2.4, PHP7.0, SSL enabled.

Here is the code I use for sending data:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$targIP/curl.php");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $pathCer . "xxx.crt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pathCer . "yyy.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $pathCer . "zzz.key");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // "2": Check that the common name exists and matches the host name of the server

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
            array ('action' => "newupl", 'data0' => $inPart0, 'data1' => $inPart1, 'data2' => $inPart2 ));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Code used on the receiving server:

```
...
$data2 = $_POST['data2'];
$data2 = html_entity_decode($data2);
$inputData2 = json_decode($data2);  // NOTE: this line produces 'Syntax error' when $data2 grows beggir then app 15 kB.
...
```

Thanks in advance to Everyone!

Comment: What's inside `$data2` after calling `html_entity_decode` when sending 51+ records?

Comment: the inside is json-encoded-like text, but what I noted on it is:  1. the text finishes on the middle of a record, e.g. {"id":821,..,"dt":"2017-12-15 11:08:46","prc  2. inside the text itself most of records seem ok, but some - also end in the middle, like this:  
{"id":532,...,"un":"itm[{"id":821,..

Comment: Could you check what's truly sent by your sending script using something like Wireshark to know whether the issue lies in the sending or the receiving side ?  Or at least check directly what's inside `$_POST['data2']` (using both might prove useful to pinpoint where the issue lies, since it could be curl, your Apache, or whatever framework / env your sending code is built on).

Comment: I did decoding and echoing the json-encoded string on the SOURCE server prior to sending it out. It lookes correct regardless of array size, even when the received string is messed up. Wireshark won't help much, as SSL encripts everything in the middle..)